# JS, Ajax and why the script i wrote can't open the XML file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I'm having trouble with my Javascript and I can't find a way to fix it even with the researches I did.

I'm trying to call a function that use Ajax to read an xml file but I can't load the file the way I want.
If I call my function LoadXML() from my HTML page, the function works fine. (I get the content of my XML file)
If I call my function LoadXML() from my JS function langue(), it doesn't work. (The XML file doesn't load)

I'm calling langue() in my HTML page when someone choose an option in a dropdown menu.

Function LoadXML():

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "resource-fr-fr.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            alert("ok")
        }
})
```

Function langue():

```
localStorage['langue'] = document.getElementById('languages').value
localStorage.removeItem('filexml')
LoadXML(); //this doesn't work i can't see the alert('ok')
var test = localStorage['filexml'];
console.log(test);
location.reload(false);
```

How i call langue() in my HTML:

```
<select id="languages" onchange="langue()">
    <option value="en-us">English</option>
    <option value="es-mx">Mexicano</option>
    <option value="fr-fr">Français</option>
</select>
```

How i tested LoadXML() in my HTML:

```
 window.onload = LoadXML(); //This works i see the alert('ok')
```

Is there something I did wrong ? If it's the case, how can I fix it? Do you know a better way to do it ?

Comment: We have not enough information to tell you why it is not working, but my first guess is the scope of the function: `onchange="langue()"` is in the window scope and `function LoadXml` is not.

Comment: any error in the console? (NOTE: your test should be `window.onload = LoadXML;`, without brackets. With your version, `LoadXML` is executed as soon as the code is reached, not on window load).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I will try this thank you

Comment: @Kaddath Nothing appear in the console, except the thing i want ( console.log(test); return nothing because there is nothing inside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a few other try, i fixed it.
 I placed the function Langue() inside my LoadXML()

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "resource-"+document.getElementById('languages').value+".xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        //Delete the old language
        localStorage.removeItem('filexml')
        //Load the new XML language file inside localStorage as a string
        $(xml).find('data').each(
              function () {
                  console.log("I'm inside")
                  localStorage.setItem('filexml', localStorage["filexml"] + "#" + $(this).attr('name') + "$" + $(this).find('value').text()); //Nom de la branche (Data name) + Valeur de la branche (Value)
                  i++;
              });
        //Change the language
        langue();
    }
})
```